# Cygwin - Header not found

Tags: cygwin

I try to compile something via a Makefile and get the following error:

[image]

I checked if the package is installed:

[image]

socket.h is uner usr/includes/sys

Any hint how to get rid of the error?

Edit:
uname -a output:
CYGWIN_NT-6.1 PC66358 3.1.2(0.340/5/3) 2019-12-21 15:25 x86_64 Cygwin

Comment: Always show the output from `uname -a` when asking a cygwin question.

Comment: Please show code and output as text, formatted as code, not as images.

Comment: Are you sure you're running Cygwin's `make`?  Are you sure you're running Cygwin's `gcc`?  What do `which make` and `which gcc` output?

Comment: Thanks. The `which` command was the solution. GCC pointed to a older version and GCC wasnt installed in the cygwin packe. Installed gcc-core, changed the PATH variable and everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely missing the proper package, as you have not used correctly cygcheck.
The check for which package contains a file is:

```
$ cygcheck -f /usr/include/sys/socket.h
cygwin-devel-3.1.2-1
```

Note the full path including the first `/`
and to verify that the package is properly installed you should use:

```
$ cygcheck -c cygwin-devel
Cygwin Package Information
Package              Version        Status
cygwin-devel         3.1.2-1        OK
```

Your command is asking the Cygwin WebSite server
where you can find some files

```
$ cygcheck -p usr/include/sys/socket.h
Found 6 matches for usr/include/sys/socket.h
cygwin-devel-3.0.7-1 - cygwin-devel: Core development files
cygwin-devel-3.1.1-1 - cygwin-devel: Core development files
cygwin-devel-3.1.2-1 - cygwin-devel: Core development files
cygwin32-2.10.0-1 - cygwin32: Cygwin 32bit toolchain
cygwin32-2.6.0-1 - cygwin32: Cygwin 32bit toolchain (installed binaries and supp
ort files)
cygwin32-2.8.2-1 - cygwin32: Cygwin 32bit toolchain
```

So it gives you current and old versions of `cygwin-devel` and of the 
`cygwin32` as it has a file called

```
usr/i686-pc-cygwin/sys-root/usr/include/asm/socket.h
```